# How do I detect that my application is running as service or in an interactive session?

Tags: c++, windows-services

I'm writing an application that is able to run as a service or standalone but I want to detect if the application was executed as a service or in a normal user session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can query the process token for membership in the Interactive group.

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330:

> SID: S-1-5-4
>
> Name: Interactive
>
> Description: A group that includes all users that have logged on interactively. Membership is controlled by the operating system.

Call GetTokenInformation with TokenGroups to get the groups associated with the account under which the process is running, then iterate over the sids looking for the Interactive sid.

I found a nice chunk of code at http://marc.info/?l=openssl-dev&m=104401851331452&w=2

Comment: This was marked as the answer. Is it true that the Interactive SID identifies logged on and never SCM processes, though the SCM may assign an interactive account to the service it launches?

Comment: @user574771 Yes, this is correct. Service processes are assigned the `NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE` SID S-1-5-6. This can be easily verified e.g. using sysinternal's Process Explorer.

Comment: This answer looks better but I am so in a rush that I would have preferred a stripped code snippet to be written here instead of linking externally. For this reason I used and upvoted the @Hongzi answer below instead.

Answer (score 14):

If this is a C++ application, somewhere in your startup code you have to call [StartServiceCtrlDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If it fails and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT`, the app has not been started as a service.

Comment: Be ware that StartServiceCtrlDispatcher can fail throwin errors that you cannot catch with try/catch!

Comment: Specifically, `GetLastError()` will return `ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT`.

Comment: This should be the accepetd answer IMO

Comment: The problem is that `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` can be called only once; it can't be used as a query. You have to pass the complete list of services. That means you can't call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(dummy)` first to device whether you need to call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(realTable)` next.

Comment: Yes, that's what Microsoft say to do.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/debugging-a-service

BTW: ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT = 1063

Answer (score 10):

Another option would be to use System.Environment.UserInteractive
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx

**Update**: To make up for posting a .NET answer to a C++ topic, I provide a C implementation based on the [.NET implementation.](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6cc686f5800feffb3f04bf48487cdfbd7b48a32d/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Environment.Windows.cs#L142-L162)

```
BOOL IsUserInteractive()
{
   BOOL bIsUserInteractive = TRUE;

   HWINSTA hWinStation = GetProcessWindowStation();
   if (hWinStation != NULL)
   {     
     USEROBJECTFLAGS uof = {0};     
     if (GetUserObjectInformation(hWinStation, UOI_FLAGS, &uof, sizeof(USEROBJECTFLAGS), NULL) && ((uof.dwFlags & WSF_VISIBLE) == 0))
     {
       bIsUserInteractive = FALSE;
     }     
   }
   return bIsUserInteractive;
}
```

Comment: @bogdan, oops sorry, a moment of identity crisis there :) BTW. the .NET implementation does something similar to what Serwood Hu suggest, except that it checks the dwFlags member of the USEROBJECTFLAGS if WSF_VISIBLE is set then it is an interactive user session.

Comment: I have verified that System.Environment.UserInteractive will return true for a service that is running in the LOCAL SYSTEM account with user interactive privileges, which makes it unusable to determine if the program is running as a result of a CMD window or the SCM.

Comment: @user574771, that is correct. As of windows Vista Interactive services are not supported, so you might want to investigate an alternative to that. Also you might want to read the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This question was good and this answer is a good one IMHO, but I had a need to also verify if I was running in the console session (ie, attached to the physical machine, not just an interactive session running remotely). I found this good to detect that:

`DWORD consessid = (DWORD)-1, appsessid = (DWORD)-1;
if ((consessid = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()) != (DWORD)-1 && ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &appsessid) && consessid == appsessid)
    printf("On console.\n");`

Windows 10 obviously, and yes this is a decade later, but... :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can base your detection on the fact that services are running with SessionID 0 and user accounts do have other values (like 1).

```
 bServiceMode = false;
 SessionID=-1;
 Size=0;
 hToken = NULL;
 (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
     GetLastError();

 if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenSessionId, &SessionID, sizeof(SessionID), &Size) || !Size)
     return FALSE;
 if(SessionID==0)
    bServiceMode = true;
```

Comment: Well if you are right then EVERYTHING on my machine is a service ... everything has a SessionID of 0.

Comment: That's only going to work starting with Vista; under Windows 2000 and XP, the first interactive session is 0.

Comment: I think they changed this on Windows XP SP2.

Comment: No, it was changed in Vista.

Comment: This method isn't reliable, because a process can be started in Session 0 with a logged on user's token.

Answer (score 2):

All of the above methods are unreliable. Session Id is not necessarily 0 (at least not in previous Windows versions), Window Station is only **WinSta0** if "If the service is running in the LocalSystem account and is interacting with the desktop".
See [KB171890](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171890/en-us) for more details.

One method for detecting if a process is running as service is following:

**Please note:** Only services installed in services database will be detected with this method, but not child processes started by a service process that are not registered in the database. In this case, it would not also be a system service. *1.

```
bool IsRunningAsService(unsigned int Pid) {
    bool Result = false;
    SC_HANDLE hScm = OpenSCManager(
        0,
        SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE,
        SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE
    );
    if (hScm == 0) {
        return Result;
    }
    DWORD ServicesBufferRequired = 0;
    DWORD ResumeHandle = 0;

    DWORD ServicesBufferSize = 0;
    DWORD ServicesCount = 0;
    ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS* ServicesBuffer = 0;

    EnumServicesStatusEx(hScm, SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO, SERVICE_WIN32, 
    SERVICE_ACTIVE, 0, 0, &ServicesBufferRequired, &ServicesCount, &ResumeHandle, 0);
    // Todo: Error handling (GetLastError() results are currently bogus?)
    ServicesBuffer = (ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS*) new 
    char[ServicesBufferRequired];
    ServicesBufferSize = ServicesBufferRequired;
    EnumServicesStatusEx(hScm, SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO, SERVICE_WIN32, 
    SERVICE_ACTIVE, (LPBYTE) ServicesBuffer, ServicesBufferSize, 
    &ServicesBufferRequired, &ServicesCount, &ResumeHandle, 0);

    ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS* ServicesBufferPtr  = ServicesBuffer;
    while (ServicesCount--) {
        if (ServicesBufferPtr->ServiceStatusProcess.dwProcessId == Pid) {
            Result = true;
            break;
        }
        ServicesBufferPtr++;
    }
    delete [] ServicesBuffer;

    CloseServiceHandle(hScm);
    return Result;
}
```

*Please note, the code above should contain additional error handling, especially it should be called in a loop until EnumServicesStatusEx returns nonzero.* But unfortunetaly as I found out, `GetLastError()` always returns 1 (ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION) even if the buffer is correctly filled with data.

*1: Testing if a process was started by a service: In this case you could use a combination of other solutions. One could test, if the process has a parent (grandparent...) process that is a registered as a service. You could use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` API for this purpose. However if the parent process is already killed, things getting difficult. I'm sure there are any undocumented settings which can determine whether a process is running as a service apart from the usual suspects like SessionId = 0, WindowStation = 0, WSF_VISIBLE, No Interactive Group membership...

Comment: Why are the above methods unreliable? Please explain.

Comment: It is explained in my first sentence:  "[...] Session Id is not necessarily 0 (at least not in previous Windows versions), Window Station is only WinSta0 if [...]"

Comment: @bkausbk But you write "All above methods are unreliable". Given that stackoverflow reorders answers based on their usefulness and status of accepted answer, "All" wouldn't refer to querying the token groups?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to detect whether the application is started as a service. When you create a service with  [CreateService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450.aspx), pass in **lpBinaryPathName** parameter some additional argument, say **-s** which would indicate that your application is started as a service. Then in the application you can check for this argument. It can also possibly help when debugging, because you can test your service functionality without actually running as a service. If [StartServiceCtrlDispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686324.aspx) fails with **ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT**, you can set a flag indicating the program is running as a console application simulating a service mode, so you can skip service related API calls using this flag.

Comment: It is a way of testing whether the application MIGHT have been started as a service.

Answer (score -1):

Process in normal user session always has a window station called **WinSta0**.

```
wchar_t buffer[256] = {0};
DWORD length = 0;
GetUserObjectInformation(GetProcessWindowStation(), UOI_NAME, buffer, 256, &length);
if (!lstricmp(buffer, "WinSta0")) {
  // normal user session
} else {
  // service session
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as described. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171890