# How to check whether a process is running as a windows service

Tags: winapi

I'm doing some code in C and I want my code to be able to determine whether its running as a windows service or as a normal application, AFAIK that windows services run on session 0 on windows vista,7 and server 2008. I'm not sure if we use the undocument interface of ntdll to query process information would help about it, like if we get the PEB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.creativecodedesign.com/node/49

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668851/how-do-i-detect-that-my-application-is-running-as-service-or-in-an-interactive-se

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the processes, use [`QueryServiceStatusEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684941%28VS.85%29.aspx) and find if any of the processes match the current process ID

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you should be calling `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` if you are running a process as a service. Simply check the return code for `ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT`. This will tell you whether or not you are running the process as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the process token for [SECURITY_SERVICE_RID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: No, that is not reliable because if a service is started from command line for example it will not have this token.